# iOS Resolve DNS programmatically is returning invalid IPs sometimes

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, dns

**Hi,**

I am working on an iOS app which requires to **resolve DNS programmatically**.

Consider this as a proxy to resolve all dns queries on iPhone. I receive DNS queries from each app on iPhone and send back corresponding IPList

I have tried a couple of methods but both have same kind of responses. The one I decided to move with is given below **resolveHost** function written in objective-c and c I am calling this method from swift code.

This is how I am calling from swift, also sharing sample host/url, value of host can be any domain ("google.com, apple.com etc") or a domain/host as a result of trails when you open a site in mkwebview

let host = "www.opera.com"

let ipArray = ResolveUtil().resolveHost(host, usingDNSServer: "8.8.8.8") as! [String]

More specifically **Facebook app does not work well with IPs returned from function  resolveHost**

By not working well I mean app **does not connect to IPs** returned from the functions

Some times it returns **192.16.192.16** as part of other IPs for some hosts/domains. What is this IP?

```
- (NSArray*)resolveHost:(NSString *)host usingDNSServer:(NSString *)dnsServer
{

    NSMutableArray* result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    struct __res_state res;
    setup_dns_server(&res, [dnsServer cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
    int count;
    char** ips = query_ips(&res, [host cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], &count);
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++){
        [result addObject:[[NSString alloc] initWithCString:ips[i] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    }

    for (int i=0; i<count; i++){

        free(ips[i]);
    }
    free(ips);
    ips = NULL;

    return result;

}

char ** query_ips(res_state res, const char *host, int* count)
{
    u_char answer[NS_PACKETSZ];
    int len = res_nquery(res, host, ns_c_in, ns_t_a, answer, sizeof(answer));

    ns_msg handle;
    ns_initparse(answer, len, &handle);

    int messageCount = ns_msg_count(handle, ns_s_an);
    *count = messageCount;
    char **ips = malloc(messageCount * sizeof(char *));

    for (int i=0; i < messageCount; i++) {
        ips[i] = malloc(16 * sizeof(char));
        memset(ips[i], '\0', sizeof(16));
        ns_rr rr;
        if(ns_parserr(&handle, ns_s_an, i, &rr) == 0) {
            strcpy(ips[i], inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr *)ns_rr_rdata(rr)));
        }
    }
    return ips;
}
```

**Other Method**

```
func resolveIp(_ hostUrl:String) -> [String]{
        var ips:[String] = [String]()
        let host = CFHostCreateWithName(nil,hostUrl as CFString).takeRetainedValue()
        CFHostStartInfoResolution(host, .addresses, nil)
        var success: DarwinBoolean = false
        if let addresses = CFHostGetAddressing(host, &success)?.takeUnretainedValue() as NSArray? {
            for case let theAddress as NSData in addresses {
                var hostname = [CChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(NI_MAXHOST))
                if getnameinfo(theAddress.bytes.assumingMemoryBound(to: sockaddr.self), socklen_t(theAddress.length),
                               &hostname, socklen_t(hostname.count), nil, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST) == 0 {
                    let numAddress = String(cString: hostname)
                    ips.append(numAddress)
                }
            }
        }
        Logger.info("\(#function) validIPs:\(ips.joined(separator: "-")) url:\(hostUrl)")
        return ips
    }
```

Comment: How does it “not work well”? What result do you get, and what do you expect?

Comment: Plus add the code how are you using the `resolveHost:usingDNSServer:` method - especially interested in argument values.

Comment: You're calling `resolveHost2:...`, but you shared a code of `resolveHost:...`. What's the difference? Passing `url` to the `host` argument also looks suspicious. What is the value of `url`?

Comment: @zrzka I have provided the sample input in the question, any other mismatch information is just a type mistake, idea is I call this function to resolve host/domains/url to IPs. In actual code I am sure calling right function with right input, in order to make different from actual code I made some changes here to names of variables and functions

Comment: @MartinR IPs returned from function were never connected for only a few domain/host/url otherwise it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might have not explained the problem statement in my original question but I managed to fix the bug, so I thought I should write here my findings. 
My app works as a dns proxy, so its main responsibility was to resolve domains and return IPs.

I used **resolveHost** function to resolve the IP. This function has all the issues mentioned by **zrzka** so if somebody wants to use please do consider his points.

The problem I had was that the function returns a few IPs against specific hosts/domains which does not seem valid, I am saying invalid because these were not pingable IPs and from Wireshark I confirmed connection on these IPs were unsuccessful, even if returned IPList contains valid IP at some index it was still causing unnecessary delay due to first try on invalid IPs as they reside before valid IPs in the list.

On further investigation I came to know these invalid IPs were against answer type CNAME which depicts Alias in DNS record, I don't know I should still call them invalid or not but ignoring them did the job for me. Now I only accept A type or AAAA type answers from DNS response. I have achieved this by a simple check in the following function.

```
char ** query_ips(res_state res, const char *host, int* count)
{
    u_char answer[NS_PACKETSZ];
    int len = res_nquery(res, host, ns_c_in, ns_t_a, answer, sizeof(answer));

    ns_msg handle;
    ns_initparse(answer, len, &handle);

    int messageCount = ns_msg_count(handle, ns_s_an);
    *count = messageCount;
    char **ips = malloc(messageCount * sizeof(char *));

    for (int i=0; i < messageCount; i++) {
        ips[i] = malloc(16 * sizeof(char));
        memset(ips[i], '\0', sizeof(16));
        ns_rr rr;
        if(ns_parserr(&handle, ns_s_an, i, &rr) == 0) {
            if (1 == rr.type || 28 == rr.type) // here is the new check
              strcpy(ips[i], inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr *)ns_rr_rdata(rr)));
        }
    }
    return ips;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> 192.16.192.16

What is this IP? Perfectly valid IPv4. It resolves back to `basento.nikhef.nl`.

> Why is it returned?

I don't know. Maybe, see `resolv.h`:

```
 * Mac OS supports a DNS query routing API (see <dns.h>) which is used by
 * most system services to access DNS.  The BIND-9 APIs described here are
 * a lower-level that does not do query routing or search amongst multiple
 * resolver clients.  The results of DNS queries from this API may differ
 * significantly from the results of queries sent to the <dns.h> API.  We
 * strongly encourage developers to use higher-level APIs where possible.
```

> By not working well I mean app does not connect to IPs returned from the functions.

This has nothing to do with the name/ip address resolution.

The problem can be elsewhere. Your provider can block it, no service is running on the IP address, you're not allowed to access it, ... Many reasons.

> More specifically Facebook app does not work well with IPs returned from function resolveHost.

This doesn't make sense to me at all. You have your own app, you're resolving IP addresses in it and then saying that it doesn't work with Facebook. Frankly, I have no idea what do you mean with this.

---

Why am I answering this question? Well, you **shouldn't blindly copy & paste code** from other Stack Overflow questions or any other sites. Did a research and it looks like a copy & paste of some other answers.

Why? The code in your question doesn't handle errors, doesn't follow documentation, ... It's a pure luck that it works for you.

What if this is your problem? Did you ever consider this option?

Here's an example of `Resolver` you can use / test with your conditions. It may or may not fix your issues.

```c
#import <resolv.h>
@import Darwin.POSIX.arpa;

@interface Resolver: NSObject

- (nullable instancetype)initWithDNSServer:(nonnull NSString *)server;
- (nullable NSArray<NSString *> *)resolveHost:(nonnull NSString *)host;

@end

@implementation Resolver {
    struct __res_state *state;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    if (state != NULL) {
        // man 3 resolver:
        //
        // res_ndestroy() should be call to free memory allocated by res_ninit() after last use.
        if ((state->options & RES_INIT) == RES_INIT) {
            res_ndestroy(state);
        }
        free(state);
        state = NULL;
    }
}

- (nullable instancetype)initWithDNSServer:(nonnull NSString *)server {
    if ((self = [super init]) == nil) {
        return nil;
    }

    // man 3 resolver:
    //
    // The memory referred to by statp must be set to all zeros prior
    // to the first call to res_ninit(). res_ndestroy() should be call to free memory
    // allocated by res_ninit() after last use.
    if ((state = calloc(1, sizeof(*state))) == NULL) {
        return nil;
    }

    // 0 success
    if (res_ninit(state) != 0) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Avoid calling inet_aton later with NULL if we can't convert it to ASCII
    if (![server canBeConvertedToEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]) {
        return nil;
    }

    struct in_addr addr;

    // man 3 inet_aton:
    //
    // It returns 1 if the string was successfully interpreted ...
    if (inet_aton([server cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], &addr) != 1) {
        return nil;
    }

    state->nsaddr_list[0].sin_addr = addr;
    state->nsaddr_list[0].sin_family = AF_INET;
    state->nsaddr_list[0].sin_port = htons(NS_DEFAULTPORT);
    state->nscount = 1;

    return self;
}

- (nullable NSArray<NSString *> *)resolveHost:(nonnull NSString *)host {
    // Avoid calling res_nquery with NULL
    if (![host canBeConvertedToEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]) {
        return nil;
    }

    u_char answer[NS_PACKETSZ];

    int len = res_nquery(state, [host cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],
                         ns_c_in, ns_t_a, answer, sizeof(answer));

    // -1 = error
    if (len == -1) {
        return nil;
    }

    ns_msg handle;

    // 0 success, -1 error
    if (ns_initparse(answer, len, &handle) != 0) {
        return nil;
    }

    u_int16_t count = ns_msg_count(handle, ns_s_an);
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:count];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++) {
        ns_rr rr;
        // 0 success, -1 error
        if (ns_parserr(&handle, ns_s_an, i, &rr) == 0) {
            char *address = inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr *)ns_rr_rdata(rr));

            if (address == NULL) {
                continue;
            }

            NSString *ip = [NSString stringWithCString:address
                                              encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
            [result addObject:ip];
        }
    }

    return result;
}

@end
```

You can use it in this way:

```c
Resolver *resolver = [[Resolver alloc] initWithDNSServer:@"8.8.8.8"];
NSLog(@"%@", [resolver resolveHost:@"www.opera.com"]);
```

Output:

```
(
    "13.102.114.111",
    "52.57.141.185",
    "18.196.127.98"
)
```

Comment: yes you are right I found this code over internet, I shared here because it was not working for me as expected. As for error handling is concerned I did not make any change in the code I found but I do log if empty array is returned. The one thing I did not mention in the question is its a NEDNSProxyProvider so just learning how it works, in proxy I get flows to be resolved and I use this function to resolve and I receive traffic from all apps, other apps work fine but two of them not YouTube and Facebook. Using Wireshark I have confirmed that app do send connect request but never connected

Comment: Empty array check is not a proper error handling. Compare your and my code - there's a ton of places where it can fail. You need a help, but you're not sharing what you are doing. Look at the edit history of your question - 8 edits, new things added, clarifications, ... and now you're saying that you're playing with the `NEDNSProxyProvider`. What's next? Another surprise? Sorry for this response, but you have to update your question with **everything** what you're doing, with the code, how are you using it, with minimal reproducible example, ... Otherwise we're wasting each other's time.

Comment: Most of the edits were due to spelling mistakes and grammar mistakes, a couple of them were based on your queries so I thought I should provide some more details, but there is a limit how much details I can share. Do you think its unethical to seek for help without sharing the whole idea/concept? I still added a couple of lines to elaborate. Thank you very much for your help and suggestions I really appreciate your patience

Comment: I'm not judging if it's ethical or not and I'm not interested in the idea/concept in general. The point is strictly technical - there's an issue you've got, but to solve it, you have to provide everything - what are you doing, when you're doing it, how it affects Facebook (still not clear from the question itself), ... - in other words - provide context. You mentioned `NEDNSProxyProvider` now, but it should have been mentioned at the same beginning. Again, it's not that someone wants to learn about your idea, but all details & context matter if you need help.